# Using System.setProperty() in Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to set a Java System property `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` in my Reducer, to enforce the system to use JDK 6 Implementation of Arrays.sort method, instead of JDK8.

```
package scoring.devicestatus;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import domain.DeviceEvent;
import domain.DeviceStatus;
import domain.EndOfPeriodEvent;
import domain.PiidBoundaryEvent;
import util.DateUtils;

public class DeviceStatusReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, NullWritable> {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DeviceStatusReducer.class);

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        -->Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        .       .
        .
        try{
            .
            .
            writeToContext(key, records, context);
        }catch(Throwable t){
            logger.error("Error processing VIN: " + key.toString(), t);
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    List<DeviceStatus> reduce(Iterable<Text> values, String endDate) {
        List<DeviceEvent> events = createEvents(values, endDate);
        .
        .       
    }

    List<DeviceEvent> createEvents(Iterable<Text> values, String endDate) {
        List<DeviceEvent> events = new ArrayList<DeviceEvent>(10);
        for(Text text : values){
            List<DeviceEvent> instances = DeviceEvent.getInstance(text);
            for(DeviceEvent instance : instances){
                if(!Constants.ORPHAN_PIID.equals(instance.getProgramInstanceId())){
                    events.add(instance);
                }
            }
        }
    --> System.out.println("Reducer Class:"+System.getProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort")+" "+conf.get("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort"));
        Collections.sort(events);
        return events;
    }

    public void writeToContext(Text key, List<DeviceStatus> deviceStatuses, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String vin = key.toString();
        for (DeviceStatus status : deviceStatuses) {
            context.write(new Text(status.toCsvString(vin)), NullWritable.get());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package domain;
    public abstract class DeviceEvent implements Comparable<DeviceEvent> {

        .
        .
        .   
        @Override
        public int compareTo(DeviceEvent arg0) {
            int comparison = getTimeStamp().compareTo(arg0.getTimeStamp());
            if(comparison == 0){
                comparison = isInstalled() ? 1 : -1;
            }
            return comparison;
        }
        .
        .
        .

    }
```

I ran the jar through command line using the -D option as

```
hadoop jar jarname.jar classname -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true args
```

The reducer does bring the property into the configuration but my error still doesn't get fixed. When I print the property using the configuration.get and System.getProperty using  `System.out.println("Reducer Class:" +System.getProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort")+ " " +conf.get("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort"));`

It looks like this:

`stdout:
Reducer Class:null true
Reducer Class:null true
Reducer Class:null true
Reducer Class:null true
Reducer Class:null true
Reducer Class:null true`

`Below is the stack trace:
SysLog:
2016-10-05 16:25:21,032 ERROR [main] DeviceStatusReducer: Error processing VIN: 19XXXXXXXXXXX
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(ComparableTimSort.java:744)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:481)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:406)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:213)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:141)
    at DeviceStatusReducer.createEvents(DeviceStatusReducer.java:139)
    at DeviceStatusReducer.reduce(DeviceStatusReducer.java:43)
    at DeviceStatusReducer.reduce(DeviceStatusReducer.java:34)
    at DeviceStatusReducer.reduce(DeviceStatusReducer.java:24)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)`

I know for sure that the `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` works because it worked on my eclipse (One JVM) when I set in the Main class as `System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort","true")` but doesn't work on the Hadoop Cluster(Multiple JVMs). I also tried setting this directly in Reducer as `System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort","true")`.

How do get the property to spread on all the JVMs? Or How to make a configuration property as a System property? Thanks

Comment: Try using mapreduce.reduce.java.opts option to pass the option to reducer JVM.

Comment: Like -D mapreduce.reduce.java.opts= -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true ?

Answer (score 1):

It works by running the jar as

```
hadoop jar JarName.jar MainClassName -D mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true args
```

Note that there is a space after -D for hadoop properties and no space after -D for setting JVM properties.